# How can I get the filename of the most recently modified PDF file in my temp directory?

Tags: pdf, filenames

I'd just like to get the filename of the most recently modified PDF file in my /tmp/ directory, using elisp. Is there a function for that?

Comment: If the thing which is *writing* the file to the tmp directory is also under the control of Emacs, it would be cleaner if you weren't guessing at the filename it created.  Potentially have Emacs create a tmp filename and pass *that* to the program to use.  YMMV, and your original approach probably does the job for you in practice, but I'd be looking for a way to not have to rely on it.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(shell-command-to-string "ls -t /tmp/*.pdf | head -1")`